Generate jOOQ java table classes without the database/schema in the package
I'm running the jOOQ generation tool (jdk11+ trial version) and it generates correctly Java classes for each table, however the package includes the database name and the schema. I want to omit these two in the package. I'm running this on SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition.
java -classpath jooq-3.19.9.jar;jooq-meta-3.19.9.jar;jooq-codegen-3.19.9.jar;jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.0.jar;r2dbc-spi-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar;reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar;mssql-jdbc-12.6.2.jre11.jar;. org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool ss.xml

It generates the package:
package dbmetab.bank_dd_0002.dbo.tables;

and I need the package to be:
package dbmetab.tables;

this is ss.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd">
  <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
  <jdbc>
    <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=localhost;databaseName=bank_dd_0002;encrypt=false</url>
    <user>abc</user>
    <password>xxx</password>
  </jdbc>
  <generator>
    <!-- The default code generator. You can override this one, to generate your own code style.
         Supported generators:
         - org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator
         - org.jooq.codegen.ScalaGenerator
         Defaults to org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator -->
    <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>
    <database>
      <!-- The database type. The format here is:
           org.util.[database].[database]Database -->
      <name>org.jooq.meta.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase</name>
      <!-- The database schema (or in the absence of schema support, in your RDBMS this
           can be the owner, user, database name) to be generated -->
      <!-- All elements that are generated from your schema
           (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions)
           Watch out for case-sensitivity. Depending on your database, this might be important! -->
      <inputSchema>dbo</inputSchema>
      <includes>
           app_dates|dates|holidays|banks|bank_groups|bank_group_banks
      </includes>
      <!-- All elements that are excluded from your schema
           (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions).
           Excludes match before includes, i.e. excludes have a higher priority -->
      <excludes></excludes>
    </database>
    <target>
      <!-- The destination package of your generated classes (within the destination directory) -->
      <packageName>dbmetab</packageName>
      <!-- The destination directory of your generated classes. Using Maven directory layout here -->
      <directory>C:\appdir\src\main\java</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>


The manual section about mapping generated catalogs and schemas has an example showing how to map your source catalog and schema to the default catalog and schema:
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <inputCatalog>my_input_catalog</inputCatalog>
      <outputCatalogToDefault>true</outputCatalogToDefault>
      <inputSchema>my_input_schema</inputSchema>
      <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
    </database>
  </generator>
</configuration>

This will effectively omit their generation. You can also remove them from being rendered in your SQL queries at runtime.
